# Test or Check Reverse DNS on a Linux / Unix

Tags: nat

I have linux server installed with RHEL. My network is configured with natted IPs.
I am confused how can I set the RDNS.A public IP is bonded with server but ifconfig shows only privet natted IP 10.1.... like that